# shared memory size beyond sysconfig limit

Tags: linux, ipc, shared-memory

can ftruncate be used to increase the size of shared memory block beyond the shared memory limit size given by sysconfig? How do I make it use swap in case physical memory runs out?

Comment: /dev/shm size by default is 50% of total physical memory. How can I let my C application on linux use swap space in case the 50% limit is all used up. Default behavior is it gives an error "no space left on disk".

Answer (score 2):

> can ftruncate be used to increase the size of shared memory block ...

`ftruncate()` resizes a file. It does not resize a memory mapping of that file. So, the answer is no.

> ... beyond the shared memory limit size given by sysconfig?

That limit can not be breached. `root` user can change that limit though.

> How do I make it use swap in case physical memory runs out?

Assuming *it* is a memory mapped file, one way is to only map parts of the file at a time, rather than the whole file. If a process uses more virtual memory than there is available physical memory the operating system is going to automatically use swapping to free some physical memory for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that the file dumped by process 1 needs to be loaded up again by process 2. So even if I mmap parts of the file, I do ultimately need to dump the entire file for the following process to consume it. And I need to use the swap.

Comment: Sorry, can't quite understand your question.

Comment: I need a 20 GB file stay in shared memory block, while my physical RAM is 20GB, but /dev/shm/ is 10GB. I don't have root permissions.

Comment: You can store the file as a disk file and map that into memory. You don't need to keep it on `/dev/shm`.